# DataBinder.Eval and negative values with spaces?

Tags: c#, data-binding, string-formatting

I have this code:

```
DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Value", "{0:#,##.00}")
```

It works nice for values like 5000 or -5000 for example. Having - 5000 makes the result ,00. Any ideas how to avoid that? If someone entered - 5000, the result should be -5000 (no space).

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this :

server code :

```
 public  class MyClass
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }


  List<MyClass> k = new List<MyClass>();
        k.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            Value = "-5000"
        });

        k.Add(new MyClass()
        {
            Value = "- 5000"
        });
        rpt.DataSource = k;
        rpt.DataBind();
```

in the aspx :

```
  <span> <%#       ((MyClass)Container.DataItem).Value.Replace(" ","")%></span>
```